# static variables inside Objective-C blocks?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

I'm working on some CoreAnimation stuff. A navigation controller with a few view controllers. And the view controllers have UISCrollViews for different "pages" of a "brochure." On each page, there might be some animation that gets triggered when the user flips to that page.

I was trying something like this (for one-shot animations).

```
void (^animationBlock)() =
  ^{
    static bool alreadyTriggered = NO;
    if(alreadyTriggered)
      return;

    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:
     ^{
       alreadyTriggered = YES;
     }];

    // Do me some animations...

    [CATransaction commit];
  };

  NSMutableDictionary* pageBlocks = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  [pageBlocks setObject:[animationBlock copy] forKey:<animation's name>];
  [self.animationBlocks setObject:pageBlocks forKey:<some page number>];

  [pageBlocks release];
  [animationBlock release];
```

"animation's name" and "some page number" are placeholders for the sake of explanation (they are arbitrary NSString literals).

And the code that triggers these animations is:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  int pageNumber = floor(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x / self.scrollView.frame.size.width);
  NSMutableDictionary* pageBLocks = [self.animationBlocks objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"page%i",pageNumber]];
  [CATransaction begin];
  for(id key in pageBLocks)
    ((void (^)())[pageBLocks objectForKey:key])();
  [CATransaction commit];
 }
```

So far so good, only that If I pop the brochure from the navigation controller (aka calls dealloc on the brochure) and then push it in again, the static bool is still set.

**My thoughts:**

**- am I retaining the block?**
 I don't know.. I'm calling release after adding it (with copy) to the dictionary and also the brochure's dealloc method calls release on the dictionary.

**- am I keeping another copy of the static bool somewhere?**
My first bool is allocated when I declare the block as static within the scope of a method.. well depends on Objective-C's activation record scheme which I haven't looked into. But assuming so, that copy is gone when releasing the object on popViewcOntroller. And another copy of it from invoking copy on the block when adding it to the dictionary should be released when the dictionary is killed?

**am I retaining the whole brochure object itself?** I didn't completely get it from the Apple docs, but they say if I access an instance variable by reference I retain self. I tried releasing self from inside the block and everything keeps running just fine...?

Comment: I don't think you should mix `copy` with `Block_release()` [Blocks Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH5-SW1)

Comment: eh? That's the way to move a block from the stack to the heap

Comment: The document suggest that you should `balance a Block_copy() with Block_release()` and `balance copy or retain with release (or autorelease)`

Comment: Sorry, I'll correct my example. I tried using both version [copy] [release] and the macro ones. That's not the issue

Comment: If you want the `BOOL` to refer to an instance of brochure why not make it an ivar instead of a static?

Comment: the bool refers to the animation block not the brochure. The brochure object (subclass of UIViewController : <UISCrollViewDelegate>) has many pages and each page might trigger an animation block. Each block defines a specific animation and the bool is for the block to know to not reexecute if it has already. Only throughout the lifespan of the brochure. When the brochure is popped the blocks should be gone. When the brochure is reinstantiated and pushed, the whole thing should take place again

Comment: 1. Your calls look balanced so there is no leaked block. 2. I'm not sure but this `static` is behaving the way I would expect e.g. it is allocated once across the lifetime of the program. 3. It's hard to say as you have left most of the implementation off but what you have so far does not present any retain cycles

Comment: The idea is simple: a view controller with a dictionary with "animation" blocks. each animation block internally has a alreadyTriggered BOOL. so each bool pertains to the block it is defined in. the static behavior i'd expect is that each BOOL inside each block retains its value as long as the viewController under which's scope the blocks are created is alive. Once the view controller is popped, it is deallocated and so should the blocks and so should their static BOOLs

Comment: Ok I just realized something out of what you said: the static is alive throughout the program's (and not the object's) lifecycle? I'd assume it'd live in a method's activation record. But I just declared a static int in an object's init with one value, then change it to another and even if I dealloc the object and re alloc it, the value now stays to the changed one. So the static is behaving as in a C++ static data member?

Comment: a static variable works just like a global one--except it's scoped to the function body where it's declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the block return a value and then decide whether or not to remove the block from the dictionary.

```
// ...
    BOOL shouldRemove = block();

    if (shouldRemove) {
        [pageBlocks removeObjectForKey:key];
    }
// ...
```

---

Let's test the static variable

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject
@end

@implementation TestClass

- (void(^)(void))block;
{
    return [[^{

        static BOOL staticBOOL = NO;

        NSLog(@"%d", staticBOOL);

        staticBOOL = YES;

    } copy] autorelease];
}  

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *p = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    TestClass *test1 = [[TestClass alloc] init];
    test1.block();
    test1.block();

    TestClass *test2 = [[TestClass alloc] init];
    test2.block();
    test2.block();

    [p release];
}
```

This outputs

```
#=> 2012-04-23 00:43:38.501 Untitled[8380:707] 0
#=> 2012-04-23 00:43:38.503 Untitled[8380:707] 1
#=> 2012-04-23 00:43:38.503 Untitled[8380:707] 1
#=> 2012-04-23 00:43:38.504 Untitled[8380:707] 1
```

How do we solve the problem? I would probably remove the object from the dictionary once it had been executed like this

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
{
    NSInteger pageNumber = floor(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x / self.scrollView.frame.size.width);
    NSMutableDictionary *pageBlocks = [self.animationBlocks objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"page%i", pageNumber]];

    [CATransaction begin];

    for (id key in [pageBlocks copy]) {
        void (^block)(void) = [pageBlocks objectForKey:key];
        if (block) {
            block();
        }
        [pageBlocks removeObjectForKey:key];
    }

    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

Comment: right I thought about that, but the problem is not all animation blocks are "one shot". Some should actually reexecute each time and not be removed from the dictionary. So I need a way for the block to set itself to one shot or not.

Comment: ehhh... I mean sure... but it's not elegant enough (for my taste within the scope of this project at least, no offense). My thought was that the block behaves sort of like a thread and must have it's own stack of sorts.. so there's got to be a way for it to keep internal state throughout calls

Comment: Well make the blocks give a return value and then decide whether to remove it from the dictionary based on that.

Comment: way it looks like now is, unless someone tells me theres' a way for the block to keep an internal variable across invocations, you should make your last suggestion into an answer and I'll take that one

Comment: and btw, I'm starting to think there shouldn't actually be a way for the block to keep internal state, if indeed it's supposed to be a kind of first-class function ala Lambda calc.

Comment: Blocks are actually Objective-C objects

Comment: Are you sure? I don't think so since they are usable within C.. they seem more like souped up pointers to functions

Comment: [Blocks Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH3-SW1) `Although blocks are available to pure C and C++, a block is also always an Objective-C object.`

Comment: Did this not answer your question?

Comment: Ok so they are objects.. then we are back to how does a block keep an internal state (aka a variable whose value will persist across invocations but that will be destroyed and reallocated across release, alloc cycles) ? Maybe I'll create another question then

Comment: It may be an object but I don't know how you would/if you even can subclass it. Either way this is not very pragmatic, you have a working solution.

Comment: I realize we are on the border of pragmatism at this point. Thing is, the question was what's the deal with statics inside a block. The "short" (and only so far) answer is: same as in an object: they are bind to the program / global scope. Now my question has turned to how do they keep internal state, but I'll ask that in separate question

Answer (score 0):

Your comment

> So far so good, only that If I pop the brochure from the navigation
>   controller (aka calls dealloc on the brochure) and then push it in
>   again, the static bool is still set.

seems to imply you want a `BOOL` member variable on the pushed view controllers... If that's correct you can achieve this using `objc_setAssociatedObject()`.

I might add a category to UIViewController to achieve this:

```
@interface UIViewController (OneShotAnimation)
@property ( nonatomic ) BOOL animationHasBeenPlayed ;
@end

@implementation UIViewController (OneShotAnimation)

-(void)setAnimationHasBeenPlayed:(BOOL)b
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject( self, @"animationHasBeenPlayed", [ NSNumber numberWithBool:b ], OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC ) ;
}

-(BOOL)animationHasBeenPlayed
{
    return [ objc_getAssociatedObject( self, @"animationHasBeenPlayed" ) boolValue ] ;
}

@end
```

Comment: oh.. but Brochure is your pushed view controller, and it's being dealloc'd... so this won't help

Comment: Right... like I told Paul, the bool is not for the view controller. The bool was intended as a way for the many blocks kept in the controllers' dictionary to each know if they should replay or not. It's supposed to be part of a block's "internal state" regardless of the view controller that they happen to be declared inside of. So one bool per block

Comment: sounds like your block needs a member variable. You can still use `objc_setAssociatedObject`

Comment: well that won't work it you're copying blocks around I don't think.. so you need an external dictionary.. if you gave each block a name/key you could recall if a block has been played based on it's name... but maybe there's an entirely different approach you could use.. this sounds complicated